# How to remove a object from an array in react hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a list of buttons and they are multi selectable. when I select the buttons I want to add , it will be added to the array perfectly and turned to blue and when I click on a already selected button it should be get removed from the array and turned to white but it doesn't. Below shows what I tried so far.

The first array (products) is to save the API data. Second one is to save the selected products.

```js
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
const [selectedProducts, setselectedProducts] = useState<any>([]);
```

```
{products.length !== 0 ? (
    products?.map(
        (item: any, index) => (
            <SButton
                key={item.key}
                label={item.value}
                onClick={() => {
                    selectedProducts(item);
                }}
                isSelected={item.selected === "YES"}
            />
        )
    )
) : (
    <p>No products</p>
)}
```

```
function selectedProducts(item:any){
    if(selectedProducts.length !== 0){
        selectedProducts.map((selecteditem:any)=>{
            if(selecteditem.key == item.key ){
                item.selected = "NO";
                setselectedProducts(selectedProducts.filter((item: any )=> item.key !== selecteditem.key))
            }else{
                item.selected = "YES";
                setselectedProducts([...selectedProducts, item]);
            }
        })
    }else{
        setselectedProducts([...selectedProducts, item]);
        item.selected = "YES";
    }
}
```

Comment: use arr.splice() method to remove the product from the selectedProducts if the the item already selected ... if you want further help then give an code snippet or codepen or any online ide you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState();

{(products.length > 0) ? (
 <Fragment>
   {products.map((item)=>{
     const {key, value, selected } = item;
     return (
       <SButton
        key={key}
        label={value}
        onClick={() => {
          setSelectedProduct(item);
          const newState = !selected;
          products.forEach((p)=>{
            if (p.key === item.key) p.selected = newState;
          });
          setProducts([...products]);
        }}
        isSelected={selected}
       />
     );
   })}
 </Fragment>
): (
 <p>No products</p>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using *selectedProducts* both as function name and name of selected products state.

Second, you should not assign values to *item*. Use spread operator instead.

Also, you can access the previous state from *setState* instead of using state directly.

```
function removeFromSelectedProducts(item: any) {
    // Set selected to 'NO' in products array
    setProducts((prevProducts) =>
        prevProducts.filter((product) =>
            product.key === item.key ? { ...product, selected: 'NO' } : product
        )
    )
    // Remove product from selectedProducts
    setSelectedProducts((prevSelectedProducts) =>
        prevSelectedProducts.filter((product) => product.key !== item.key)
    )
}

function addToSelectedProducts(item: any) {
    // Set selected to 'YES' in products array
    setProducts((prevProducts) =>
        prevProducts.filter((product) =>
            product.key === item.key ? { ...product, selected: 'YES' } : product
        )
    )
    // Add item to selectedProducts
    setSelectedProducts((prevSelectedProducts) => [...prevSelectedProducts, { ...item, selected: 'YES'}])
 }


function selectProduct(item: any) => {
    if (selectedProducts.some((product) => product.key === item.key)) {
        removeFromSelectedProducts(item)
    } else {
        addToSelectedProducts(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this using [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook instead of using separate functions for addition & removal of selected products.